# Unsatisfied dependency Exception

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application where I need to store image into a local folder and its details like id,name and path in db.I done this with no problem. Now I want to edit the name in the folder as well as in db. I succeeded in renaming the file in the folder and i want to rename in db as well. I have written code for this but i got error like unsatisfied dependency. In my controller

```
@PutMapping("/updateFile")
public String updateFile(@RequestParam String oldFileName,@RequestParam String newFileName,@RequestParam UUID imageId,@RequestParam ImageModel imageModel) throws IOException {
    // UUID Id=UUID.fromString(imageId);
    imgserv.updateImageData(imageId, imageModel);
    return fileStorageService.updateFile(oldFileName, newFileName);
}
```

and in service implementation

```
@Override
public String updateImageData(UUID imageId, ImageModel imageModel) {
    ImageModel imageData = imageRepo.findImageById(imageId);
    if (imageId == null) {
        return "Image Data Not Found";
    }
    imageData.setImageName(imageModel.getImageName());
    imageRepo.save(imageData);
    return "Image Details Updated Successfully!";
}
```

and my Repository class

```
@Repository("imageRepo")
public interface ImageRepo extends MongoRepository<ImageModel, UUID> {
    ImageModel findImageById(UUID imageId); 
}
```

and my error code is like

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fileController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'imgserv'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'imgserv': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'imageRepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'imageRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property id found for type ImageModel!
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:586) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:372) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:572) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>       at

Comment: have you autowired imageRepo and imageRepo?

Comment: yes.@Service("imgserv")
public class ImageServiceImaplement implements ImageService{

 @Autowired
 private ImageRepo imageRepo;